# What do different icons and symbols in Android Studio's Structure sidebar mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, structure, legend, sidebar

When I click on 'Structure' sidebar in Android Studio, it displays the contents of the current class. However there are certain icons & symbols used to indicate different members, e.g., a circle with letter m for methods, etc. Where do I get the complete list and the details for all the icons & symbols? (something like a legend/key that explains the various icons & symbols is what I'm looking for)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the link below and you will get your answer about different icons and symbols in Android Studio's Structure sidebar:
https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html

Edited:

> **Static class initializer** means >>> class object creation with class name and its properties.
>   **Show_Something_Fragment** means >> FragmentView helps to showcustom view i.e. foe example if a Fragment is inside its main activity then it helps to show the view of the fragment layout.
>   **Outbound_changed_event** means >> different attributes taken for an event.

Hope now your doubts are clear.......

Comment: Dear Sid, seems the jetbrains link doesn't have the explanation for all symbols. For example I couldn't find these two symbols: 1. a circle with = in it (https://goo.gl/photos/zrDHHfFfqX36VPxB6). 2. two tiny black symbols to the top left and bottom left of the main symbol (https://goo.gl/photos/bsSoYhqaMHU91ngJ6). The android developer link is of no use. I have already seen it before asking the question. It doesn't contain the explanation for the symbols. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: One more new symbol to the bottom right of main symbol: https://goo.gl/photos/j1jcML9THNBXc5Le8

Comment: thanks for the extra information. But I'm not interested in the explanation of the text following the symbols. That text is created by me. Anyways, I found the answer to the little symbols appearing over the main symbol in the link itself (though not obvious at first sight): left top (pin) - final; left bottom (diamond) - static; right bottom (lock) - read-only class from an external jar.

Comment: Anyways I thank you for the original jetbrains link. If no one else replies, I will check your answer as the most helpful.